# how to resove the scroll conflict between scrollview and flatList in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a flatList and some views in the scrollView, how to make when the flatList scroll to top, we start to scroll flatList not scrollView.

```
<ScrollView>
  <View>
    // some child views
  </View>
<FlatList
  data={this.props.sourceData}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
 />
<View>
  ....  // some child views
</View>
```

Comment: try taking your <Flatlist /> out of the <Scrollview>

Comment: The UI effect is diffent when move flatlist out

Comment: You should consider thinking about why you want to use both ScrollView and Flatlist. ScrollView renders all its react child components at once, but this has a performance downside. ... FlatList renders items lazily, when they are about to appear, and removes items that scroll way off screen to save memory and processing time. So in fact, they will show up the same thing eventually, but you have to decide if it is important that they are loaded all at once, or they can be loaded "lazy" and increase performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the scroll conflict is complex, you can try to move the header views into FlatLIst
ListHeaderComponent, and the footer views into the ListFooterComponent

```
 <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    ListHeaderComponent={"your header component"}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    ListFooterComponent={"your bottom views"}
  />
```

you can also [read my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074258/react-native-scroll-tab-which-content-is-flatlist-in-scrollview-how-to-resolve), in the description I give some solution. I hope it can help you

Comment: This 100%. I've used this pattern in my own apps to great effect.